# How do i clear the user login for git in Visual Studio Community Edition?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

We had a user make a commit to GitHub on this machine in Visual Studio and when it asked for login, they clicked for it to always remember their login. It now won't prompt for username/password, but we want to change it.

How do we clear the login?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/08/29/clearing-the-credentials-for-connecting-to-a-team-foundation-server/

You need to go into Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage Network Passwords. Then find the github account and delete it.